# Javascript dropdown options 0-100 increment by .5

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that is creating the values for a dropdown on my page. I am currently incrementing by 5, (0-100).

I am trying to change this to increment by `.5` instead but it keeps just returning `0-100` with no increment.

My expected output is `0,.5,1,1.5,2,2.5 ... 100`.

Here is my function so far:

```
/**
 * Generate our possible error scores
 */
function generateErrorScores() {

    var min = 0,
        max = 100,
        multiplier = 5, // Tried .5 here
        list = [];

    // Loop between min and max, increment by multiplier
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        if (i % multiplier === 0) {
            list.push(i);
        }
    }

    return list;
}

console.log(generateErrorScores())
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3y451jga/

I have a feeling its `if (i % multiplier === 0) {` causing the problem but I am not sure how to adapt it to the `.5` increments.

Comment: Why not just do `for( var i=min; i<=max; i+=multiplier)`???

Comment: Changing `i++` to `i += 0.5` might do the trick of incrementing by 0.5.

Comment: Why don't you just increment by multiplier instead?.. http://jsfiddle.net/3y451jga/2/ That's weird. I mean, is there any reason why you're using the modulus here?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the list `[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, ..., 100]` you could do:

```js
/**
 * Generate our possible error scores
 */
function generateErrorScores() {
  const multiplier = 0.5
  return [...Array((100 / multiplier) + 1)].map((x, i) => i * multiplier)
}

console.log(generateErrorScores())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to just do this

```
for (var i = min; i <= max; i+=0.5) {
    list.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if (i % multiplier === 0)` serves no purpose. That works if you need multipliers off a list, but in this case you need fractions.

Interestingly, your comment is correct ("increment by multiplier") but the code is not doing that. A valid solution would be something like this:

```
function generateErrorScores() {

    var min = 0,
        max = 100,
        segment = .5,
        list = [];

    // Loop between min and max, increment by segment
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += segment) {
        list.push(i);
    }

    return list;
}

console.log(generateErrorScores())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just increment the `i` by `0.5` and you will get your expected output, there is no need for extra check here.

```
 for (var i = min; i <= max; i+=0.5) {
```

```js
/**
 * Generate our possible error scores
 */
function generateErrorScores() {
  var min = 0,
    max = 100,
    multiplier = 0.5,
    list = [];
  // Loop between min and max, increment by multiplier
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i += 0.5) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  return list;
}
console.log(generateErrorScores())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateErrorScores() {

 var min = 0,
  max = 100,
  increment = 0.5,
  list = [];

 // Loop between min and max, increment by multiplier
 for (var i = min; i <= max; i = i + increment) {
  list.push(i);
 }

 return list;

}

console.log(generateErrorScores());
```